# Difference in output between similar while loop and do while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, compare, do-while

For my Java class, I was asked to create a while loop and then convert it to a do-while loop and then compare the output. This is the question:

> 5. Replace the while loop in question 4 with a do while loop.  What is the possible difference between the output from question 4 and this question?

I can't find a difference in the output, possible or not. Here is the code and output for both below.

while loop

```
package fordemo;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ForDemo {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Input a number:");
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int number = user_input.nextInt();
    int n = -1;
    while (n < number){
        n=n+2;
        System.out.print(n + " ");

    }
  }
}
```

run:

```
Input a number:
15
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

do-while loop

```
package fordemo;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ForDemo {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Input a number:");
    int number = user_input.nextInt();
    int n = -1; 
    do {
        n+=2;
        System.out.print(n + " ");
    }
    while (n < number);            

  }
}
```

run:

```
Input a number:
11
1 3 5 7 9 11 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: why don't you input a number less than `-1` and check what happens?

Comment: give input less then -1 then u see the difference

Comment: do-while loop
`run:

Input a number:
-9
1 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)`

Comment: @IAmTheWalrus: Then do the same with the `while` loop, and you have your answer. Paxdiablo tells you why.

Comment: while loop 
`Input a number:
-11
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)`

Comment: @IAmTheWalrus - Then I believe you got your answer.. `Do while` prints `1`. `while` doesnt. The `why?` part ahs been expained by *paxdiablo*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between `while (condition) {something}` and `do {something} while (condition)` is that the latter always executes *at least once.*

The former checks the condition *before* the iteration, the latter checks it *afterwards.*

If you enter `-1` or less, the former will give you nothing  and the latter will give you `1`.

In its simplest form, you can look at the difference between the two lines:

```
while (false) { System.out.println("x"); }
do { System.out.println("x"); } while (false);
```

The former complains bitterly about unreachable code because it never enters the loop. The latter does not complain because it runs the loop once.

Answer (score 1):

A do while loop will execute at least once whereas a while loop may not even execute even once if its conditions are not met. The do while starts checking its condition after the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The while statement continually executes a block of statements while a particular condition is true. The difference between do-while and while is that do-while evaluates its expression at the bottom of the loop instead of the top. Therefore, in your case if you input value less then `-1` `while loop` will executes `0` times whereas `do-while` loop will executes `1 times`

Answer (score 0):

The first time running the while loop, n is set to -1, then it checks if n

In the do-while loop your code sets n to -1, then raises it with 2. Prints the line and after that it checks if n

So if you input is -1 the while loop wont print anything (because -1 < -1 evaluates to false). But your do-while loop will print 1

Answer (score 0):

**first test the condition then execute the body**

```
  while (n < number){   // Top tested loop or (pre test loop)
            n=n+2;
            System.out.print(n + " ");

        }
```

**first execute the body of the loop and then test the condition;**

```
do {
        n+=2;
        System.out.print(n + " ");
    }
    while (n < number);   // Bottom tested loop (post test loop)
```